# Store object into array and group all array with the same value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I'm working on array right now and I need to arrange this based on value.

```
{
        "data": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "second evaluation form",
            "emp_position": "System Architecture",
            "rating": 5,
            "segments": [
                {
                    "segment_name": "Job Role ",
                    "question": "How old are you?"
                },
                {
                    "segment_name": "360 Segments",
                    "question": "What is your food?"
                },
                {
                    "segment_name": "360 Segments",
                    "question": "sample question"
                },
            ]
        }
    }
```

What I need to do is to store this object into array and group all question based on segment_name like this:

```
{
    "data":[
         {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "second evaluation form",
            "emp_position": "System Architecture",
            "rating": 5,
            "segments": [
                {
                    "segment_name": "Job Role "
                    "question_collection": [
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "question": "How old are you?"
                        }
                    ]


                },
                {
                    "segment_name": "360 Segments",
                    "question_collection":[
                        {
                           "id": 1,
                           "question": "What is your food?"
                        },
                        {
                             "id": 2,
                            "question": "sample question"
                         }
                    ] 
                },

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is what I've tried to do:

```
 $array_value =[];       
        foreach ($query AS $key => &$data) {
            $array_value['id'] = $data['id'];
            $array_value['title'] = $data['title'];
            $array_value['emp_position'] = $data['position'];
            $array_value['rating'] = $data['rating_count'];                                  

            if ( is_array($data) ) {
               $array_value['segments'][$key]['segment_name'] = $data['segment'];                                  
               $array_value['segments'][$key]['question'] = $data['question'];                                  
            } 

        }
```

Comment: You can make segments as collection and then use groupBy function of collection.

Comment: You need to change your expected output as object/array can not contain duplicate key. `"question_collection":[
                        {
                           "question": "What is your food?"
                        },
                        {
                            "question": "sample question"
                         }
                    ]`

Comment: @Bluetree I think I'm lucky that you found my question. I need to change my array from before. hope you could help me with this one again. :))))

Comment: @B.Desai yeah your right. let me update my post above

Comment: @alyssa in your question_collection `id` . is it coming from `$data['id']`?

Comment: from where the hell `id's` came suddenly? I have no clue? Please let us know

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have to add Id for me to avoid error in angular when I loop it using ngFor

Comment: @Bluetree No, the data['id'] is for evaluation and the id in question is the id from question table

Comment: @AlyssaAndrea  in your input there is no id, but in output you suddenly added? How we can know that from where it coming from or what logic you applied for this to show in your expected outcome. And did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```
<?php

$json = '{
        "data": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "second evaluation form",
            "emp_position": "System Architecture",
            "rating": 5,
            "segments": [
                {
                    "segment_name": "Job Role ",
                    "id": 4,
                    "question": "How old are you?"
                },
                {
                    "segment_name": "360 Segments",
                    "id": 1,
                    "question": "What is your food?"
                },
                {
                    "segment_name": "360 Segments",
                    "id": 2,
                    "question": "sample question"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
';

$query = json_decode($json,true);

$segment_array = [];
foreach($query['data']['segments'] as $arr){
  $segment_array[$arr['segment_name']]['segment_name'] = $arr['segment_name'];
  $segment_array[$arr['segment_name']]['question_collection'][] = ['id'=>$arr['id'],'question'=>$arr['question']] ;
}

$query['data']['segments'] = array_values($segment_array);

echo json_encode($query,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

OUTPUT:- https://eval.in/902194

Comment: hi thanks for response :))) your code almost work but im having a problem on merging to my original array

Comment: @AlyssaAndrea  i have edited my answer completely.Please check now. Hope it will worked for you.

Comment: @AlyssaAndrea  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

Collection function might help you find your solution.

```
$json = '{"data":{"id":2,"title":"second evaluation form","emp_position":"System Architecture","rating":5,"segments":[{"segment_name":"Job Role ","question":"How old are you?"},{"segment_name":"360 Segments","question":"What is your food?"},{"segment_name":"360 Segments","question":"sample question"}]}}';

    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    $coll = collect($array['data']['segments']);
    $coll = $coll->groupBy('segment_name');
    dump($coll);
```

Hope this helps you.Let me know if any problem

Comment: thanks for your response :))) As I tried your code I dunno why I'm always having a problem with json_decode." json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: make sure that $json is a string you can check it using gettype() to check variables type

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, You can loop by array and group all keys

```
$json = '{
        "data": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "second evaluation form",
            "emp_position": "System Architecture",
            "rating": 5,
            "segments": [
                {
                    "segment_name": "Job Role ",
                    "question": "How old are you?"
                },
                {
                    "segment_name": "360 Segments",
                    "question": "What is your food?"
                },
                {
                    "segment_name": "360 Segments",
                    "question": "sample question"
                }
            ]
        }
    }';

$data = json_decode($json,true);


$segments = $data['data']['segments'];
$new_segemnts = array();
foreach($segments as $segemnt)
{
    $key = $segemnt['segment_name'];

    $new_segemnts[$key]['segment_name']=$segemnt['segment_name'];
    $new_segemnts[$key]['question_collection'][]=array("question"=>$segemnt['question']);

}
$data['data']['segments'] = array_values($new_segemnts);
echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/0YGEh)

Answer (score 1):

Here try my answer. I've just editted your existing code so you won't confuse that much. Nothing much to explain here. I included some explaination in my comment.

**CODE**

```
$array_value =[];       
foreach ($query AS $key => &$data) {
    $array_value['id'] = $data['id'];
    $array_value['title'] = $data['title'];
    $array_value['emp_position'] = $data['position'];
    $array_value['rating'] = $data['rating_count'];                                  

    if ( is_array($data) ) {

        // Check if segment is already added
        $has_segment = false;
        $segment_key = null;

        foreach($array_value['segments'] as $key2 => $val){
            //If segment is already added get the key
            if($val['segment_name'] == $data['segment']){
                $segment_key = $key2;
                $has_segment = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if segment does not exists. create a new array for new segment
        if(!$has_segment){
            $array_value['segments'] = array();
        }
        // If new segment, get the index
        $segment_key = count($array_value['segments']) - 1;

        // If new segment, create segment and question collection array
        if(!array_key_exists('question_collection', $array_value['segments'][$segment_key])){
            $array_value['segments'][$segment_key]['segment_name'] = $data['segment'];    
            $array_value['segments'][$segment_key]['question_collection'] = array();
        }
        //Add the id for question collectiona rray
        $array_value['segments'][$segment_key]['question_collection'][] = array(
            "id" =>  $data['question_id'],
            "question" =>  $data['question']
        );            
    }
}
```